# Marionette.js: HTML Escape <%- %> in Underscore template: variable empty

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

I'm experiencing an odd situation where I am loading my Marionette.js templates from .tpl files and I have something like:

```
<input id="address" type="text" name="address" value='<%- address %>' placeholder="Enter Address"/>
```

The above does not show the value of address. If I change it to <%= address %> it works no problem.

Not really sure what the issue could be, and I couldn't find any other questions related specifically to this problem. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It honestly doesn't seem to matter what the variable's value is. I've tried on multiple variables with no success. So, it could simply be a string of "foo" and it's still empty.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle example of the broken code?